# Random 404 error when fetching data from backend (Symfony/React + Axios)

Tags: axios, fetch, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to build an app with modules one can validate and files attached to them, with an upload service, etc.
I'm just working on the fetching part for now, just trying to fetch the modules and files names and characteristics.
When trying to access some of the module's data by clicking on the module's page, I get a 404 error on **some** of them. The strange thing is, I don't get this error on all of them, and for some the fetching works perfectly. I checked my data, tried to reboot my database, but the problem persists. I don't get why some work and some don't, it seems to be completely random.

I just want to fetch files when clicking on the module's page.
With Thunder Client when performing on my back-end, I get a 200 OK response on the same module that will give me 404 error on front-end.
I tried putting on a relative path in the URL part of the Axios request ("`/api/module/${id}/files`" for example), but this doesn't work at all when doing so and sends me 404 errors everytime I try to access to a module page, so that's why I left an absolute path.

Here's my Axios service for fetching files by module (the 'fetchAllModule' function is used on the dashboard page and works perfectly):

```
import axios from "axios";
import { File, Module } from "./entities";

export async function fetchAllModules() {
    const response = await axios.get<Module[]>(`http://localhost:8000/api/module`);
    return response.data;
}

export async function fetchOneModule(id:number) {
    const response = await axios.get<Module>(`http://localhost:8000/api/module/${id}`);
    return response.data;
}

export async function fetchModuleFiles(id:number) {
    const response = await axios.get<File[]>(`http://localhost:8000/api/module/${id}/files`);
    return response.data;
}
```

I also set up an [id].tsx page, which fetches data with SSR (and contains an uploader service; I don't think this has anything to see with our problem, but I'm still showing you in case):

```
import { fetchModuleFiles, fetchOneModule } from "../../module-service";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import { File, Module, User } from "@/entities";
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { GetServerSideProps } from "next";
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import CloudUploadIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CloudUpload';
import LinearProgressWithLabel from "@/components/LinearProgressionWithLabel";
import { postFile } from "@/file-service";
import ItemFile from "@/components/ItemFile";

interface Props {
    module: Module;
    files: File[];
}

const VisuallyHiddenInput = styled('input')({
    clip: 'rect(0 0 0 0)',
    clipPath: 'inset(50%)',
    height: 1,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
    width: 1,
});

export default function ModulePage({ module, files: filesProps }: Props) {
    const [files, setFiles] = useState(filesProps);
    const [file, setFile] = useState<File>({
        filePath: ''
    });

    function handleFile(event: any) {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => setFile({
            ...file,
            filePath: String(reader.result)
        });
        reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
    }

    async function handleSubmit() {
        await postFile(module.id, file);
        window.location.reload();
    }

    return (
        <Grid
            container
            direction="column"
            alignItems="center"
            justifyContent="center"
        >
            <Box>
                <Typography variant="h3" gutterBottom>
                    {module.name}
                </Typography>
                <LinearProgressWithLabel value={module.progression} />
                <Typography sx={{ mb: 1.5 }} color="text.secondary">
                    {module.status} par {module.validatingPerson?.firstname} {module.validatingPerson?.name} le {dayjs(module.validationDateTime).format('DD-MM-YYYY à HH:mm')}
                </Typography>

                <Typography variant="h5">
                    Fichiers
                </Typography>
                {files.map(file =>
                    <ItemFile file={file} />
                )}
                <Button
                    component="label"
                    variant="contained"
                    startIcon={<CloudUploadIcon />}
                    sx={{ my: 2 }}
                >
                    Télécharger un fichier
                    <VisuallyHiddenInput
                        type="file"
                        onChange={handleFile}
                    />
                </Button>
                <Button
                    sx={{ display: 'flex' }}
                    type="submit"
                    variant="contained"
                    onClick={handleSubmit}
                >
                    Publier
                </Button>
            </Box>
        </Grid>
    )
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<Props> = async (context) => {
    const { id } = context.query
    try {
        return {
            props: {
                module: await fetchOneModule(Number(id)),
                files: await fetchModuleFiles(Number(id))
            }
        }
    } catch {
        return {
            notFound: true
        }
    }
}
```

If you need any other information on my config, let me know!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Have updated my initial post with what seems to me as a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I think I found the solution to my problem: I switched my fetching with SSR to a fetching with useEffect, and it worked!